# Why does it throw exception and says: "Validation failed for query"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I try to get roles of user, providing his username, but for some reason I get: Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.Set library.data.UserRepository.findRolesByUsername(java.lang.String); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Set library.data.UserRepository.findRolesByUsername(java.lang.String).

Here is my User entity-class:

```
@Entity(name = "\"User\"")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private final String username;

    @NonNull
    private final String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @NonNull
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"
            ))
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

Here is my Role entity-class:

```
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private String authority;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<User> users;

    @Override
    public @NonNull String getAuthority() {
        return authority;
    }
}
```

And the repository itself:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT u.roles FROM User u WHERE u.username Like :username")
    Set<Role> findRolesByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
}
```

I've tried another queries, verifying correctness of mapping, asking chatbots but nothing helps me and I am starting to loose my mind, help me please.

Comment: Hm, since two users can match the query, dupicate roles might fetch. Try to use List instead of Set.

Comment: also try to use an optional, that is more java fuctional oriented

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help, the same exception. By the way, besides exception I mentioned, I noticed another one: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'User'. I try to guess, that User is reserved key-word in SQL, but i am unable to write in query "user" this might be the problem, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used quotes in the User table, which is causing some issues. You can avoid this error by adding `nativeQuery` keyword in your query as below.  Also note that I have improved the query if you really need to use “like”.

```
@Query(
        nativeQuery = true,
        value = "SELECT u.roles FROM User u WHERE lower(u.username) like lower(concat('%', :username, '%'))"
)
Set<Role> findRolesByUsername(String username);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the join on role in your query. Change your query to `@Query("SELECT role FROM User u JOIN u.roles role WHERE u.username like :username")` and change the return type to `List<Role>`. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may want to change the 'like' to '='. You can potentially get roles across users when using 'like'.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help, the same exception. By the way, besides exception I mentioned, I noticed another one: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'User'. I try to guess, that User is reserved key-word in SQL, but i am unable to write in query "user" this might be the problem, no?

Comment: Your entity annotation looks in error. Don't escape the table name or just use ```@Entity```.